# NotifyIcon in WPF not appearing, probably issue with IconStream

Tags: c#, wpf

```
            string title = "Executing...";
            string msg = "Executing " + jobName;
            int time = 5000;
            NotifyIcon nIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            Stream iconStream;
            System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            iconStream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("WpfApplication1.Resources.Visual Basic Script.ico");
            nIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
            nIcon.ShowBalloonTip(time, title, msg, ToolTipIcon.Info);

            return instanceID;
```

I have this block of code in a method, with the icon Visual Basic Script.ico as an embedded resource. When I run the application, the notifyicon does not appear. I think it has to do with the GetManifestResourceStream but I am not sure how to fix it. I've searched for several hours; would really appreciate some assistance.

EDIT:
I've tried these things:
The file is in a resource folder and is marked as an embedded resource
I call the namespace WpfApplication1 with the subfolder and the resource
=> WpfApplication1.Resources.Visual Basic Script.ico
Can't seem to find any other common mistakes.

Comment: `GetManifestResourceStream` will return `null` if the resource is not found.

Comment: What is the proper resourcestream syntax?

Comment: Remove spaces from the filename, make sure it's in the folder `Resources` and check the file properties that it's embedded.

Comment: Thanks Mathew. The property is marked as embedded resource and it is in the folder Resources. Will check if the namechange will help. If the namespace is marked as "namespace WpfApplication1" in front of the code WpfApplication1.Resources.filename should work, yes?

Comment: Yes, this should work. I do this all the time. 3 common problems. 1) wrong assembly. 2) wrong namespace. 3) resource not embedded. Why not try this `GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(...)`. Maybe you have the wrong assembly.

Comment: Hmm. So edit the code to look more like this?:  
Stream iconStream;  
                iconStream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WpfApplication1.Resources.VBS.ico");  
                nIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);  
                nIcon.ShowBalloonTip(time, title, msg, ToolTipIcon.Info);